# Why aren't these lines getting covered by code coverage?

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage

I'm using Visual Studio 2010's code coverage feature. I've made several unit tests to test a method, but the code coverage is telling me that three blocks are not getting completely covered. The problem is, I don't see how these blocks can be only partially covered. Notice that the return statements ARE covered, so clearly the branch has been taken. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: are you in 'debug'? If not, perhaps these lines are being optimised away such that line X of the code file is no longer a separate line

Comment: Also, I wouldn't get hung up on code coverage

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I also disagree with the closing of this question. Seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I agree the reason for the lack of coverage will lead to an understanding of code coverage workings that then has a referenece example to help further understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that endDate is nullable. Even though I handle null cases at the top, the code coverage wanted to see the null situation dealt with at each branch with endDate in it.

Comment: I would say that the code coverage tool was doing more than code coverage but was also applying some sort of branch coverage and applying it's own rules - you probabaly won't see this if you use other code coverage tools such as NCover, OpenCover or PartCover etc etc...